# Access historical street view images

Tags: maps, google-street-view

My house has a historical street view dating back to 2014 but the house to the left and right goes back to 2009. How can i get the street view for those earlier years for my house?

I have emailed customer support but no reply.

I have use the time slider in street view

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the Street View API then there is currently no way of obtaining historical images. However, if you're trying to access historical images of your house via maps.google.com then the slider on the top left corner will show you the different years available for your house. If no option is available for the selected address then there is no historical image for that address.